# ProgressBar in vb.net 2005

Tags: vb.net

I want design my startup screen with progress bar. But I don't how to process it with the CPU Process.

Could anybody help me to solve the code?

Thanks,
Sopolin

Comment: Can you please clarify the question?  Do you want a splash screen while your app is loading?  What do you mean by "the CPU process"?

Comment: Do you know startup screen? Example: Window, when it startup, it load startup screen with progress bar?

Comment: Does any of the below that I've just added help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you already designed your splash screen ? And displaying correctly ?

The progress bars that are displayed during startup, display the progess of the application starting up, e.g you might have 3 processes that the application does at startup, initialise variable, open database connection, load config. You would give each of these a percentage on the progress bar and as they are completed, set the progress bar to that value

Sorry if I've missed your point

The Progress bar itself is easy to use, you set the min and max value (I've set it to 100 to repressent 100%)

```
progressBar1.Maximum = 100
progressBar1.Manimum=0
```

And then you set the amount of percentage done with a command like

```
progressBar1.Value = 20
```

More details can be found at

[Progress bar](http://www.vbdotnetheaven.com/UploadFile/mahesh/ProgressBar04262005051817AM/ProgressBar.aspx)

-- To add a splash screen

To add a splash screen to an application, in the solution explorer, click add new item -> Splash screen, then if you for to properties of the project (solution explorer) at the bottom of the application screen, is splash screen, select the form you want to use as the splash screen, in order to the progress bar use the code above (you will need to drop a progress bar from the toolbox onto the form)

Comment: I accept your answer, but I am a new programmer. Yes, I want to design startup screen. I don't how to design or write code with progress bar.

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Class Form4

  Private Sub Form4_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim x, p As Integer
    ProgressBar1.Maximum = 100
    ProgressBar1.Step = 1
    For x = 0 To 100
        ProgressBar1.Value = p
        p = p + 1
    Next
    // any other action
  End Sub
End Class
```